# Simplify exporting all files in a folder to import them using 'destructered import'

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, export, module.exports

I have a folder `extractors` with a bunch of files each containing a function. (*Yes, I have my reasons why I've seperated it*). I want to export all of the files in a way that allows me to import them (destructered):

```js
const { ..., ..., ...} = require(...);
```

---

First things first, my current code works. *However*, I'm trying to find a better solution since the way I'm doing it now feels a bit '*janky*'.

Currently, I have an `index.js` file in the `extractors` folder which exports the files:

```js
const AccountData = require('./Account');
const BitmojiData = require('./Bitmoji');
//...

module.exports = {
    AccountData,
    BitmojiData,
    //...
}
```

This allows me to use:

```js
const { AccountData, BitmojiData, ... } = require('./extractors/index.js');
```

And prevents me from having to do:

```js
const AccountData = require('./extractors/AccountData.js');
const BitmojiData = require('./extractors/BitmojiData.js');
//...
```

However, I can't help but feel like what I'm doing is.. '*suboptimal*'. So I'm trying to find a better solution, but couldn't find one.

I hope someone is able to help me out, thanks in advance!

**Example function `/extractors/Example.js`**

```js
const Example = (data) => {
   //...
   return ({
      k: 'v'
   })
}

module.exports = Example;
```

*Also, I'm pretty sure I'm on ES5, I can't use `export default` etc.*